# Стоит ли ждать Android NDK под arm64/aarch64?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, apple, m1

Недавно поставил себе UserLAnd и развернул Linux прямо на Android смартфоне, поставил студию, jdk-11 для arm, sdk и... что насчет ndk? Проект, который я (ради интереса) хочу скомпилировать, содержит C-код, а найти ndk для arm я не смог. Единственное - то, что Google прямо сейчас пилят arm под ndk для процессоров M-серии от Apple. Но будет ли поддержка .. "телефонных" arm архитектур, может кто обьяснить? Просто, как я понял, у Apple есть Rosetta, ретранслирующая x86 инструкции процессора для arm, значит ли это то, что ndk будет работать не в целом под arm, а только на процессорах apple? Т.е. этот самый ndk запустить будет невозможно на raspberry pi?

Чтобы без лишних вопросов: идея создать приложение для разработки приложений на рутированном девайсе, ибо мощности мобильных процессоров растут и, к примеру, мой снап 888 компилит шаблонный проект студии с нуля за 30 секунд.

[offtop]Идея больше из спортивного интереса, поэтому не критикуйте, я прекрасно понимаю, что компьютерные мощности выше, но комп сейчас уже стал роскошью, а единственное приложение для этих задач - AIDE - встало в развитии лет 5 назад :)[/offtop]

Comment: Можете не ждать и попробовать собрать его самостоятельно. cmake вроде как собирается под arm, и clang наверное тоже, на счет остального - не знаю. Если там какие-то инструменты с закрытыми исходниками - то тогда наверное только ждать...

Comment: @user7860670, есть termux-ndk, но он кривой :( придется ждать, если, опять же, я все правильно понял, что делает google